# Validate that a URL entered in a form is from a specific website with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, url

I have a website where people post links from Google+. I am trying to make sure that people can only post specific links from Google plus. An example would be, someone would need to post a link like 
https://plus.google.com/games/907809777960/params/%22%7B%5C%22encPrms%5C%22%3A%5C%22eyJiYXBpVGlja2V0SWQiOiI4MzFhNGQ0Ny0yYTU4LTQ2OTktYmI1Yy1hN2ExYTAzY2U4ZTMiLCJsYW5kaW5nUGFnZSI6Im5ld3NmZWVkL2JvbnVzYWJsZUZlZWQvbWFydmVsY29tcGxldGUvNTQ3Mjc3LzEzMTQ0NzA0MjUvMCIsInJlZl9pZCI6IjEwOTkyODAzNzUzNzQ2Mjk5NzAxMCIsInRyYWNrIjoibmV3c2ZlZWQtYm9udXNfbWFydmVsQ29tcGxldGUtMCIsInNlbmRfdGltZXN0YW1wIjoiMTMxNDQ3MDQyNyJ9%5C%22%7D%22/source/3. 
I want to make sure that the link starts with or at least contains https://plus.google.com/games/907809777960/params/, if not, it will not submit the link and alert that the link is invalid. The code I have so far is.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"> 
function checkForm(theForm) {
if (form.bonuslink.indexOf("https://plus.google.com/games/907809777960/params/") == -1)
    { alert('You can only enter authentic Google + links'); return false; }             
else { 
return true; }
}
</script>
<form action="submitbonus.php" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);" method="post">
 Bonus Link: <input name="bonuslink" type="text" size="40" />  <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit Bonus" /><br />
</form>
```

I cannot get it to work for some reason. It submits every time regardless of what it typed. I am not that familiar with javascript, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: indexOf: `This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.`

Comment: I have done it where i place -1 instead of 0 in the field but that dosent work either.

Comment: Use `==` for comparisons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit edit: you have two problems you need to reference the bonuslink value not the DOM element itself and you need to call it as a member of the 'theForm' instead of 'form' since that is what you called the parameter. Other than that everything should be fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"> 
function checkForm(theForm) {
    if (theForm.bonuslink.value.indexOf("https://plus.google.com/games/907809777960/params/") == -1){ 
        alert('You can only enter authentic Google + links'); 
        return false; 
    } else { 
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
<form action="submitbonus.php" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);" method="post">
 Bonus Link: <input name="bonuslink" type="text" size="40" />  <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit Bonus" /><br />
</form>
```

Comment: Ameer. I tired it and that didn't work. I dont know if I am checking the form wrong or what. It seems to be submitting and avoiding the javascript call completely. I updated my code in the question as well.

Comment: Have you attached event handler to submit?

Comment: I copied your code exactly, but it is still submitting no matter what I type. you can view the site I am working on here. http://gpluscow.com/bonustest.php

Comment: sorry I wrote it but I didn't add it, you need to change bonuslink to bonuslink.value, I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

this regular expression will extract the domain name from any string.
basically it'll return the part starting from http:// etc.

```
/((https?|s?ftp|dict|www)(://)?)[A-Za-z0-9.\-]+)/gi
```

it'll detect the following forms:

> - http://www.google.com
> - https://www.google.com
> - ftp://www.google.com
> - dict://www.google.com
> - www.google.com

enjoy.