# Match two urls with regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of urls and I want to match those url's with this url using regular expressions

```
http://investor.somehost.com/*
```

here * means anything after that or you can say it's a wildcard...

```
String href = url.getURL();
```

here href contains all the url's.

suppose firstentry contains that above url (`http://investor.somehost.com/*`)

So how can I compare href with firstentry such that if href starts with this url then do this thing...

Comment: In case you're interested in the regular expression, you could either  *find* `^http://investor\.somehost\.com` or *match* `http://investor\.somehost\.com(/.*)?`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to determine whether a String starts with a particular prefix, use [`startsWith(String prefix)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29).

Example:

```
String href = "http://google.com/mail";
if(href.startsWith("http://google.com")) {
    //... Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Yeah I can do that... But what about * after the url, it means anything ... So anything can come after `investor.somehost.com/(anything)`. So If I am using startswith it will also check for * right. But I want some regular expression that can match this *... And I have to compare list of urls with the urls in text files basically...

Comment: Please see my code example. Every time your prefix will change to contain the relevant url. We only include the part of the string we're interested in matching in the prefix and drop the `*` part.

Answer (score 1):

```
"^http://investor\\.somehost\\.com/"
```

will match any string starting with `http://investor.somehost.com/`.  If you want only valid URLs, you could use

```
"^http://investor\\.somehost\\.com/(([-._~:@!$&'()*+,;=a-zA-Z0-9]|%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])+(/([-._~:@!$&'()*+,;=a-zA-Z0-9]|%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])*)*)?"
```

If you want to allow queries,

```
"^http://investor\\.somehost\\.com/(([-._~:@!$&'()*+,;=a-zA-Z0-9]|%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])+(/([-._~:@!$&'()*+,;=a-zA-Z0-9]|%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])*)*)?(\?([-._~:@!$&'()*+,;=a-zA-Z0-9]|%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])*)?"
```

If you also need fragments,

```
"^http://investor\\.somehost\\.com/(([-._~:@!$&'()*+,;=a-zA-Z0-9]|%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])+(/([-._~:@!$&'()*+,;=a-zA-Z0-9]|%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])*)*)?(\?([-._~:@!$&'()*+,;=/?a-zA-Z0-9]|%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])*)?(#([-._~:@!$&'()*+,;=/?a-zA-Z0-9]|%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])*)?"
```

End any of these with `$` if you don't want to allow trailing (non-URL) parts of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I have a regular expression on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216666/validate-that-a-url-entered-in-a-form-is-from-a-specific-website-with-javascript/7216868#7216868) that provides the regular expression to extract the domain part of a url no matyer where in a string it mau occur. Its for javascript so remove the leading '/' amd trailing '/ig'. Use it to extract the domains and compare them with a simple equals check.